How to align a UI element to its left position in Unity
filled health bar
I am trying to add a health bar to my game. It looks like this in hierarchy:

HealthBar

Red (The red bar behind)
Green (The green bar at the front)
Text (The number at the left)


When the bar is filled, it looks normal as the image above. But when I decrease the width of the green bar from the Rect Transform component,
green bar centered
it looks like this. The green bar's level decreases from both left and right.
How can I make it stay at left, and only decrease from right?

Please include how you configured/setup your health bar.

@BugFinder is there anything else i should include? i explained how the health bar works, there's a red bar behind and green bar front. i change the green bar's width from rect transform.

why would you center the green bar if you dont want it to act centered? most people in a bar like this use a progress bar..

@BugFinder does Unity have a built-in progress bar as a ui element though?

as I said, its called a progress bar

Please check out Video you'll get an idea of aligning Helthbar in Unity
